# Global variables in Vue.js when using CLI template

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, command-line-interface

I need to declare a global variable that can be accessed by all components in my Vue.js app. All components should be able to change its value. I am using CLI template.
Any suggestions?

Thank you 
Dhiaa Eddin Anabtawi

Comment: which error? How did you add it exactly?

Comment: @MarcoPantaleoni Forget about the error. it maybe syntax error or something. Still my queston is how to declare a global variable that can be accessed by different separate components?

Comment: The "best" way is to use Vue's state management store - [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general in vue it's not possible/recommended to directly change a property in a parent scope. The way communication happens is by passing props to child components and to send back events (possibly with values) to parents (see [Passing Data to Child Components with Props](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props) and [Sending Messages to Parents with Events](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-to-Child-Components-with-Props)).

If you want to have easily accessible global state, a clean way to do it is to use a "store" as described in the [State Management](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html) chapter of the vue guide:

```
var store = {
  state: {
    message: 'Hello!'
  },
  setMessageAction (newValue) {
    this.state.message = newValue
  },
  clearMessageAction () {
    this.state.message = ''
  }
}

...

var vm = new Vue({
  ...
  data: {
    sharedState: store.state
  }
  ...
})
```

then you can use `this.$root.$data.sharedState` to access the global state, for exampe using `this.$root.$data.sharedState.message` to read the message or `store.setMessageAction()` to modify it (assuming you are importing the `store` symbol).

That said, at this point, you would be much better served by using [vuex](https://github.com/vuejs/vuex), the official solution for centralized state management, which is easier, cleaner and less error-prone.

Comment: Thank you. It really helps.